# How to add an audio into video using ffmpeg if I have already used the filter_complex command?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm new to ffmpeg so sorry if something goes wrong.
I'm trying to combine several videos into one, add between video transitions, and add background music to this video (add music not to each video individually, but add one music file to all merged videos as a background music).
I found some lessons on how to do it. I did it through the "filter_complex" filter. I managed to merge the videos and add a transaction between them. But when i add a music file, an error occurs

Code:

```
E:\Programs\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-4.4.1-essentials_build\bin\ffmpeg.exe ^
-y ^
-i E:/Programs/ffmpeg/f1.mp4  ^
-i E:/Programs/ffmpeg/f2.mp4  ^
-i E:/Programs/ffmpeg/f3.mp4  ^
-i E:/Programs/ffmpeg/f4.mp4  ^
-i E:/Programs/ffmpeg/f5.mp4  ^
-i E:/Programs/ffmpeg/f6.mp4  ^
-i E:/Programs/ffmpeg/music.mp3 ^
-f lavfi -i color=black:s=3840x2160 -filter_complex ^
"[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; ^
 [1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[v1]; ^
 [2:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+20/TB[v2]; ^
 [3:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+30/TB[v3]; ^
 [4:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+40/TB[v4]; ^
 [5:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+50/TB[v5]; ^
 [6:v]trim=duration=30[over]; ^
 [over][v0]overlay[over1]; ^
 [over1][v1]overlay[over2]; ^
 [over2][v2]overlay[over3]; ^
 [over3][v3]overlay[over4]; ^
 [over4][v4]overlay[over5]; ^
 [over5][v5]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]" -vcodec libx264 -map [outv] -map 6:a -shortest -movflags +faststart merge.mp4
pause
```

The following error is displayed:

> [mp3float @ 000002a9a40603c0] Header missingme=00:06:30.65 bitrate=
> 123.5kbits/s speed=53.7x Error while decoding stream #6:0: Invalid data found when processing input

How to fix it ?

Comment: `[6:v]` corresponds to the video stream of "music.mp3" ? is it correct ?

Comment: I already use the [6:v] in this command: "[6:v]trim=duration=30[over]; ^"